# Xamarin Forms TabbedPage showing white space in iOS when removed

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I am using a nested TabbedPage within Xamarin Forms but would like to remove this TabbedPage from iOS as I am re-creating it and placing it at the top of the page. I have a custom renderer and inside the `ViewDidLoad` method I am using this: `TabBar.RemoveFromSuperview();`

This removes the `TabBar` but the space it occupied is still there. Does anyone know how to remove this space?

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37109477/1506387) on another question. Maybe that helps? It does the magic for you.

Comment: I've tried to add HidesBottomBarWhenPushed = True into ViewWillAppear, ViewDidLoad and ViewWillLayoutSubViews but still no luck

Comment: Could you share a simple demo

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to remove the Tab bar and then resize the height of it's frame to 0

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    this.TabBar.RemoveFromSuperview();
    this.TabBar.Frame = new CGRect(this.TabBar.Frame.X, 
    this.TabBar.Frame.Y, this.TabBar.Frame.Width, 0);
}
```