# PopToRootViewController Shows the black bar on bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

[image]

When I am in another view controller and I `popToRootViewController` on click of button. But i am getting the black bar on the bottom which is above the tabBar.

I have used following code to `popToRootViewController`.

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37040313/hiding-the-tabbar-and-removing-the-space

Comment: now its working , I have used the following line of code on `ViewWillAppear` Method `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;`