# Swift: Hide UIStackView on UIWebview Scroll

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift3, uistackview

I have a **UIWebview** on top of which is a **UIStackView**. I want to **hide** and **show** the stackview with **animation** on scroll in the webview like the effect in the chrome browser.

How do I achieve this?

P.S : This one didn't work

[iOS/Swift - Hide/Show UITabBarController when scrolling down/up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928394/ios-swift-hide-show-uitabbarcontroller-when-scrolling-down-up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ScrollView` has `scrollViewDidScroll` you can use it to detect scrolling and use method `animate(withDuration duration: TimeInterval, animations: @escaping () -> Swift.Void)` from `UIView` to change height of your `StackView`. This is probably the simplest solution.

Edit:

if you want to detect interactions earlier try `scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)`. If this also doesn't solve your problem try creating your own custom gesture and add it to scrollview.

Comment: this method works fine but it'll work only after the scroll has been completed.
I want to animate during scroll.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work after following **Axel's** advice.
Here's the code:

```
var lastContentOffset: CGPoint!

func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
}

func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if lastContentOffset.y > scrollView.contentOffset.y {
        print("Going up!")
        if topBarStackView.isHidden == true{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                self.topBarStackView.isHidden = false
            })
        }
    } else {
        print("Going down!")
        if topBarStackView.isHidden == false {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                self.topBarStackView.isHidden = true
            })
        }
    }
}
```